# Why are images missing from my k2 item objects?

Tags: php, oop, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

Thanks for helping... I am working on a custom joomla component that pulls k2 items into one of it's views... I was successful getting the k2 items into my component's view by including the k2 content modules helper and then using a little code like so:

```
<?php

$componentParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_k2');
$items = modK2ContentHelper::getItems($componentParams);

foreach ($items as $key=>$item): ?>

    <a class="Item_Title" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have most everything I need in the $item object EXCEPT images... For some reason none of the image info is being included in the object?! So I am unable to do what I was hoping and use something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" />
```

Here is a Pastebin.com link to a print_r(); I did on my $item object in the foreach:

http://pastebin.com/tJRB8wbu

I don't even see $item->image available to me :-/

How can I get the k2 item path?

Comment: It might have something do do with the fact that I am passing the $componentParams into the helper MODULE and that the component params object I am passing in doesn't have settings for images... WHEREAS the module params might... Does anyone know how to get the module params rather than the component params as I am doing above?

Answer (score 0):

It seems images in K2 is linked with the id of the article.

You should try something like this :

```
$item->image = JPATH_ROOT.'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$item->id).'_L.jpg'.
```